# Git clone through Nginx proxy for Gitlab server is not working

Tags: nginx, gitlab, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel

My Nginx Server is acting as a proxy for a Gitlab Server, the problem is when I try "`**git clone git@gitlab.example.com:username/project.git**`" I'm unable to clone the project [it is not tunneling from Nginx server to Gitlab server]

When I update my local system's /etc/hosts file with IP Address of Gitlab Server then it clones fine without password [I've updated my profile with SSH Public Key on Gitlab].

So I came to the conclusion that I've to update my Nginx Configuration with rules that can tunnel the SSH communication from any client system to  Gitlab Server through Nginx Server.

Tried the code on this [Link](https://gist.github.com/fnando/1101211) by making changes as followed:

```
upstream gitlab {
server 192.168.61.102:22;
}

server {
listen 22;
server_name gitlab.example.com;

location / {
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;

proxy_pass http://gitlab;
}
}
```

but it is not working. It would be great if someone helps me in tweaking the rules to make it work.

**Note:** In the above code 192.168.61.102 is the IP Address of my gitlab server, my Nginx server is at 192.168.61.101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to stop having Nginx listen on port 22. Nginx doesn't handle SSH forwarding, your firewall does.

If you're using iptables, then these rules will forward all requests through your Nginx host to your Gitlab host.

```sh
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination [GITLAB-IP]:22
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source [NGINX-IP]
```

You may need to change `eth0` in those commands to fit your server setup.

---

Then you need to enable packet forwarding by editing the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and uncommenting this line:

```sh
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then reload the configuration you just changed with this command:

```sh
sudo sysctl -p
```

---

Finally, those iptables rule are not persistent by default and will be erased when you reboot the server. The easiest way to make them persistent is to use the `iptables-persistent` package. You install that package like this:

```sh
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

And after it's installed you can save/restore the iptables rules anytime with these commands:

```sh
sudo invoke-rc.d iptables-persistent save
sudo invoke-rc.d iptables-persistent reload
```

If you're on Ubuntu 16.04 or later, then those commands are

```sh
sudo netfilter-persistent save
sudo netfilter-persistent reload
```

You'll want to run the save command after you get the rules working and you've tested them. Then, when your server reboots the rules you saved will be loaded automatically.

Comment: Very Informative with nice details, thank U will give it a try and post result once done but then what is the purpose/usecase of the Nginx code (Source:[link](https://gist.github.com/fnando/1101211)) I mentioned in the question, doesn't it help in my scenario?

Comment: The Nginx code is used to forward HTTP requests to your Gitlab host, but you have it set to listen on port 22, which is the SSH port. It should be listening on port 80.

Comment: Then is the code mentioned in this link with title "Nginx configuration for SSH tunnel" is giving out wrong idea?

Comment: Yeah, whoever wrote that gist seems to think that Nginx is handling their SSH tunnel, but that's not what's actually happening. They don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: On my Nginx Server I've changed my SSH port from 22 to 2201 & wrote the  rules as you have mentioned above like:                                        `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.60.101:22`
`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.60.100`

Comment: also aaded `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` /etc/sysctl.conf;                               And Installed `sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent`

`sudo invoke-rc.d iptables-persistent save`
`sudo invoke-rc.d iptables-persistent reload`

Comment: When issue the following command in Nginx Server **`ssh root@192.168.60.101 -L 22:192.168.60.100:22`** it's working fine, I'm able to connect to 192.168.60.101       But when I use **`ssh root@192.168.60.100`** from my other client systems with in network I'm unable to connect to 192.168.60.101. Not to mention **On my Nginx Server I've changed my SSH port from 22 to 2201**

Comment: Also tried by keeping the default ssh port 22 on Nginx server with the above mentioned IPTables rules no luck

Comment: It worked after using an additional command of **`sysctl -p`**

Answer (score 2):

Nginx proxy is for http requests.

When cloning through SSH, you are not using http.

What you need to do is use something like port forwarding on your router or iptables on your server.

Comment: But then what is the purpose/usecase of the Nginx code (Source:[link](https://gist.github.com/fnando/1101211)) I mentioned in the question, doesn't it help in my scenario?

Comment: The purpose of that code is to redirect http requests received on port 80 to localhost on port 3000. But it's always http traffic that is redirected. So with your code you could make your gitlab web interface accessible from the outside world etc. but you cannot convert ssh requests to http with a nginx proxy.
BrokenBinary's answer with iptables is the way to go.

Comment: Then is the code mentioned in this [link](https://gist.github.com/fnando/1101211) with title "Nginx configuration for SSH tunnel" is giving out wrong idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you change iptables rules if you haven't worked with it before. Reload ssh `systemctl restart sshd`

1. Change your SSH port, for example, to 22000. You can do it by editing the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on your reverse_proxy host.
2. Change the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file. Add the following before the http section:

```
stream {
  upstream gitlab_servers {
    least_conn;
    server  glab_server_ip:glab_server_port;
  }

  server {
    listen     22;
    proxy_pass gitlab_servers;
  }
}
```