# docker-compose gitlab with Nginx but ssh failed

Tags: docker, nginx, ssh, docker-compose, gitlab

I am use docker-compose for building Nginx and gitlab on the same server which is on GCP.
And I am using Cloudflare to manage my DNS, I have a domain name `gitlab.mydomain.com` which is binding with my GCP static IP (for example my ip is `123.45.67.89`).

So I want to use this domain to access my gitlab with Nginx, the following is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.mydomain.com'
    privileged: true
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://gitlab.mydomain.com:7788'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 9453
    ports:
      - '7788:80'
      - '9453:22'
    volumes:
      - /gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
      - /gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - /gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
    networks:
      - net-proxy
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
networks:
   net-porxy:
      external:
         name: my-network
```

And this is my `Nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gitlab.mydomain.com;
    proxy_connect_timeout       300;
    proxy_send_timeout          300;
    proxy_read_timeout          300;
    send_timeout                300;
    location ~ / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://123.45.67.89:7788;
    }
}
```

I also add this line in my `gitlab.rb` file

```
external_url 'http://gitlab.mydomain.com'
```

I changed my ssh port from 22 to 9453 port, and I can access my gitlab service by my domain `gitlab.mydomain.com`, and I can also clone my git repo with http, but when I want to clone with ssh

`git clone ssh://git@gitlab.mydomain.com:9453/myproject/myrepo.git`, it will always show operation time out.

But if I replace my ssh domain with ip:

`git clone ssh://git@123.45.67.89:9453/myproject/myrepo.git`

It's worked!!!

I'm not sure if this is because my domain was reverse proxy by Nginx. If I want to clone my repo by domain with Nginx, how can I do, please.

Comment: Dude Gitlab is down!

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38923182/6309), NGiNX does not do SSH forwarding, only HTTP.

So:

- either you no [NGiNX TCP proxying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293663/7490)
- or [GCP protocol forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding)

For example: [Port forwarding over SSH](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#port-forwarding-over-ssh)